# UIImage start and stop animating on MapView based on user interaction with map

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, mkmapview

I have a `UIImageView` that is currently animating from one point on a screen to another and back again infinitely. Here's the code for that animation:

```
CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){self.view.frame.size.width/2,     self.view.frame.size.height/2-(PIN_HEIGHT/2)-35};
CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){self.view.frame.size.width/2,  self.view.frame.size.height/2-(PIN_HEIGHT/2)-20};

CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation  animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

animation.duration = 1.f;
animation.path = thePath;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;

[userPin.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Now, this animation of the `UIImageView` is animating on top of an `MKMapView`. Here comes my question: I want the animation to be happening by default and when the user is interacting with the map. However when the user touches the map and stops interacting with it, I want the animation to stop, but be able to start again once the user moves the map again.

Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks SO much!